# set pages main html tag in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xml

I am writing a .net c# website which is available in multiple languages. How can I set the following main html tag in code behind of a page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add an id and `runat=server` to your HTML tag in your page:

```
<html id="html" runat="server" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Then in your code behind you can set whatever you'd like:

```
    html.Attributes["xml:lang"] = "somethingelse";
    html.Attributes["lang"] = "somethingelse";
```

Comment: Lovely - and is this also possible via a httpmodule do you know?

Comment: It might be if you can intercept the actual HTML response, or if you expose something in a base Page then you could get your BasePage in the HttpModule and call the member you exposed in the base page. At that point though, it wouldn't have any advantage over simply using a master or base Page to achieve the same thing.

Comment: If this answers the original question, please mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ashelvey: I did exactly as you suggested, but I get an error, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060196/adding-attribute-to-html-tag-via-code-behind-results-in-error-type-system-web-u. Could you have a look? Thanks!